# Multi level routing in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have one default module `app.module.ts` in this module I define one route like:

```
 const mainRoutes: Routes = [
      {path:'',component:FrontComponent},
    ] 
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        FrontComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FrontModule,
        AdminModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

And I have another one module `admin.module.ts` this is child of app module and I use routing for it like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin',
      component: AdminComponent,
      children:[
        {path:'',component:AdminmainComponent},
        {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
        {path:'matches',component:MatchesComponent},
        {path:'tournament',component:TournamentComponent},
        {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent}
        ]
    }
      ];

    @NgModule({const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menus', component: MenusComponent, children: [
      { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
      { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
      { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewComponent },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: CreateComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MenusRoutingModule { }
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

`admin.module.ts` contains another sub module menus module and it is child of admin, it content some compenent like  create, view, edit I want to route it like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'menus', component: MenusComponent, children: [
          { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
          { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
          { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewComponent },
          { path: 'edit/:id', component: CreateComponent }
        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class MenusRoutingModule { }
```

But I got error in console `[object object]`

Comment: i need url like http://localhost:4200/admin/menus/create

Comment: module tree is    app.module.ts--->admin.module.ts--->menu.module.ts

Comment: routes tree is app.routing.ts-->admin.routing.ts--->menus.routing.ts

Answer (score 0):

Do menus module load lazy and it will be look like:

Admin routing

```
export const adminRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "admin", (...)
    children: [

        {
            path: "admin",
            children: [
               {path:'', pathMatch:'full',component:AdminmainComponent},
               {
                  path: "menus", 
                  // if you want lazy
                  loadChildren: "./components/menus/menus.module#MenusModule"
                  // if not... then:
                  //children: [...menuRoutes]
              },
             {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
             {path:'matches',component:MatchesComponent},
             {path:'tournament',component:TournamentComponent},
             {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent}


            ]

    ]
}, ... ];
```

and in menu.module :

```
 const menuRoutes = [
        { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
              { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
              { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewComponent },
              { path: 'edit/:id', component: CreateComponent }
    ]
```

if you do something like this, then yours modules should lazy load (if you change LoadStrategy)

Comment: do you try go to this url without using router?
put url in your browser:
localhost:4200/admin/menus/create
and let me know...
because im my opinion you put some object to function navigate (Router or routerLink)

Answer (score 0):

In your app module you need to specify admin route with lazy loading

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
      {path:'',component:FrontComponent},
      {path:'admin', loadChildren: './admin.module#AdminModule'
    ] 
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        FrontComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FrontModule,
        AdminModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your admin module have the routes for admin and lazy load menu's route in the same way

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'admin',
      component: AdminComponent,
      children:[
        {path:'',component:AdminmainComponent},
        {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
        {path:'matches',component:MatchesComponent},
        {path:'tournament',component:TournamentComponent},
        {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent},
        {path:'teams',loadChildren: './menu.module.ts#MenuModule'},
        ]
    }
      ];

    export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

And define routes for your menu in your menu module